# Is it best to minimize using pointers in C?

Tags: c, bug, pointers

I think most people would agree that pointers are a major source of bugs in C programs (if not the greatest source of bugs). Other languages drop pointers entirely for this reason. When working in C, then, would it be best to avoid using pointers whenever practicable? For example, I recently wrote a function like this:

```
void split (char *record, char *delim,
            int numfields, int fieldmax,
            char result[numfields][fieldmax]);
```

While not as versatile as a dynamically allocated variable, in that it requires the programmer to know the number of fields in advance and anything over `fieldmax` is truncated (which is sometimes acceptable), it eliminates the need for memory management, and the potential for memory corruption. I think this is a pretty good trade, but I was wondering what the opinions of other programmers on this were.

Comment: "...most people would agree that pointers are a major source of bugs in C programs..."  Pointers are no more or less inherently dangerous than guns, motorcycles or sharp objects.  The greatest source of bugs in C programs is sloppy work on the part of the developer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but that code you posted won't compile.

Comment: @Blrfl > The first step toward being a great programmer is adminiting how faillible everybody is. pointer is a great tool, very powerfull, but also error prone. If you use them, you WILL make mistake sometime and mess up memory, sloppy work or not.

Comment: it does compile under gcc. gcc supports C99 VLA's

Comment: @treadmarks That would be it. Was using C89

Comment: @deadalnix:  Yep, and I've done it, too.  All I'm saying is that if you're going to use a sharp tool, learn how to use it properly and don't blame the tool if you accidentally use it to cut off your leg.  Someone who wants a language that protects them from their own mistakes should probably not be using C.  Pascal, Ada and maybe Java would be much better choices.

Comment: @Blrfl: Pascal and Ada are intriguing choices to me, but they don't seem very ubiquitous and I wonder about their library support compared to C. Are they worth the investment or are they mostly academic at this point?

Comment: Pointers don't bug programs, programmers bug programs.

Comment: @Blrfl: Pointers don't create bugs, programmers using pointers create bugs.

Comment: Your result array would seem to be the biggest problem

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Other languages don't "drop pointers entirely," they just restrict what you can do with them, give them a syntax that looks like non-pointer variables, handle some operations on them behind the scenes, and call them something else, like a reference or object.  If you ever have to make a distinction between assigning a copy of something or not, you are dealing with pointers.

With the exception of programming paradigms that pass everything by copy, with obvious performance implications, the use of pointers is unavoidable in all but the simplest of programs.  By all means, use stack variables where it makes sense, but if you try to avoid pointers too much, you will introduce a whole different breed of potential bugs.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't trying to say "never use pointers" - even the code sample I posted had pointers in it. It was about the choice between static and dynamic allocation, and if all the problems pointers can introduce should make us prefer static. But at the risk of answering my own question, I guess the choice is driven more by business requirements than anything else - if you can get away with using a static variable, why not do it?

Answer (score 38):

In my opinion, it doesn't make any sense to use C and want to avoid pointers. If you do so, then you'd better use another language.

Pointers are unavoidable in C. This is what make C so powerfull and also what make C a pain in the ass sometime. C is meant to be used with pointers.

Arrays are pointers, functions are pointers, memory allocation work through pointers, and so on. Take advantage of that or change language.

Comment: Arrays and functions aren't pointers.

Comment: @Pubby8: Arrays and pointers are closely related.

Comment: @Pubby8 technically you're correct, but the answerer's point is that to use the full expressive powers of arrays/functions you should know how using these constructs with pointers multiplies their power significantly. Not knowing pointers boxes you in significantly wrt arrays/functions.

Comment: @Pubby8 Arrays most certainly are pointers, and c doesn't even say anything about going from an array to a pointer unless you explicitly activate certain compiler warnings.  A 'function' is just a place in memory that the compiler treats as having instructions instead of data.  That's why declaring a function pointer is allowed, you're just accessing the same instructions at the same point in memory using a different name.

Comment: @Kevin Arrays implicitly cast to pointers, that doesn't mean they are. Why does `sizeof(array)` return the number of indices of an array and not the size of a pointer? And yes, a function is in memory and can have a pointer to it, but that does not mean its a pointer. That's like saying `int` is equivalent to `int *` because they both involve memory.

Comment: @Pubby8 `sizeof` works on arrays because the compiler knows how much space it's going to allot for it at compile time.  Also, `sizeof(array)` returns the number of bytes in the array, not the number of indices. And even that only works with the specified dimensions.

Comment: @Pubby8 > If you write int a, a isn't a pointer. If you write void a(){}, a is a pointer to the instructions. The same goes for array. Actually it is that true that [0]ptr works on some compilers. The int exemple doesn't stand. Now, you are right : thoses are not pointers - like the sizeof exempel shows, but cast silently to pointers because it is the whole point of C and can be considered as such 99% of the time.

Comment: Arrays aren't pointers.  This is easier to see with multidimensional arrays.  Given `double a[4];` and `double b[4][4];`, you can pass `a` around as a pointer, but `b` can't be represented as a `double **`.  @Kevin, by "C" you're referring to your specific implementation, not the language.  Even so, if you can activate warnings that an array is decaying into a pointer, that suggests that the implementation does make a difference between arrays and pointers.

Comment: Arrays are pointers. You are simply debating syntax. The fact of the matter is that an array and a pointer are substantially the same thing, yet there are certain differences in how they are created. `double a[4];` statically allocates memory along with creating a pointer to that memory. `double *a = (double*)malloc(4*sizeof(double));` dynamically allocates memory along with creating a pointer to that memory. In both cases, a is a pointer. The only difference is where the memory is. You can use `a[n]` in either case, or `*(a+n)` in either case, and it will work, because they're both pointers.

Comment: @BenRichards *"double a[4]; statically allocates memory along with creating a pointer to that memory."* Untrue. Statically allocated array will only require `sizeof(double)*4` bytes of memory. There is no separate pointer created: pointer will **always** occupy memory. When used with `a[n]`, then the **address** is *implicitly converted* to a pointer. It's not a debate about syntax; it's actually the syntatic sugar hides the fact that they are different. David Thornleys comment about multidimensional arrays highlights the problem.

Comment: Fake news all over the cyber. Arrays are pointers. Arrays arent pointers. Are. Aren't. The people don't know what to believe anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Those `char*` should really be `const`, unless you actually meant a pointer to one single character, which I find to be quite unlikely. Apart from that, pointers are the reason C is so fast- they're extremely efficient. What else are you going to do, copy everything around everywhere? The ability to alias any variable at any time is risky, but it's also very powerful.

If you don't like bugs, and you still like performance, then upgrade to C++. It's vastly less buggy when written with adherence to it's most basic principles and can be faster than C, and is certainly no slower in the general case.

Comment: `const` doesn't make the distinction between intending to use the pointer as a string or single character at a time, only whether you intend to modify the underlying data.  They still should be declared as `const`, but that's only because they're not intended to be modified (or so I infer from the declaration), and so one can safely pass a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck using the standard runtime or any third-party libraries.  If you mean you want to avoid pointer *manipulation* then you might have a chance, but I don't think you'll gain any real benefit.  It's the nature of the beast; if you want protection from pointer errors, then you'd be better off using a different language.

Answer (score 0):

The power of C comes from the fact that underline data storage is transparent to 
use. It is not really about pointers, it is more about working directly on hardware while still being a general purpose code.

While this may be of no virtue in many cases, in that case, we don't need to *drop pointers from C*, we need to *drop C from development*.

In my opinion, in your earlier version, you are *NOT* avoiding pointers. I can always supply an already corrupt (or free()ed) pointer as *record and everything will be doomed!

The core issue, though, is not really pointers! I have seen so many people don't get it right in the beginning, but even after having reasonable number of project experience, some get it, some fear it. I cann't say authoritatively, but those who have some basic exposure (introduction) to microprocessor architecture and/or OS basics, don't quite face that much trouble. It is the essence of how the machines work and C translates it in a very transparent way on higher level. If you ever *fear* pointers in C, try work on this background knowledge and lot of practice; things should work smooth. I don't quite believe that one should ever fear *C or its' pointers*.  If you have the fear, there is always a way to get over it and then start enjoying pointers in C.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you're right that only using pointers when necessary will result in fewer bugs. However, in C, almost all of the time, pointers ARE necessary.

For instance, I may be wrong, but I don't think your code sample works: I don't think the function can receive a dynamic array as an argument, so it will have to use "numfields" and "fieldmax" to calculate where to write the data -- which will scribble over random memory if the wrong sizes are passed.

And most of the time, deciding the return size in advance will be difficult. If you want to avoid pointer bugs, use C++, and use pointers only when you need to.